# Can't create Azure VM with the New-AzureVM Cmdlet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am struggling with creating a Azure VM through PowerShell. My script is very simple:

```
$VMConfig = New-AzureVMConfig -Name PemoVM -InstanceSize ExtraSmall
 -ImageName $VMImage.ImageName  |
Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows -Password $Pw -AdminUsername $UserName -EnableWinRMHttp  |
Add-AzureDataDisk -CreateNew -DiskSizeInGB 25 -DiskLabel "Standard" -LUN 0 

New-AzureVM -ServiceName pemotrain2 -Location "West Europe" -VMs $VMConfig -WaitForBoot
```

I'll get a "404 Bad Request". The error message is:

The name is not a valid storage account name. Storage account names must be between 3 and 24 characters in length and use numbers and lower-case letters only.

Obviously it has something to do with the storage account Name but I can't figure out where to put it inside one of the cmdlets.

Regards,
Peter

Update: I just forgot to set the Storage Account with my subscription (I was using an not existing name):

Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName MySub -CurrentStorageAccount portalvhds1s1q1h058p5g8

It now works as expected.

Comment: Have you tried `Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccountName "My Storage Account Name" -SubscriptionName "My Subscription Name"`?